# Head and hair of object not rendering

Tags: rendering, objects, blender-internal-render-engine

I just finished an animation of the Hulk. When I try to render the animation, the top of the head and the hair don't show up even though they do in my workspace. I asked another question regarding how the hair mesh on hulk doesn't move properly with my armature, and I have a feeling this has something to do with it. I temporarily fixed that issue by creating a skull and turning on "Bone Envelopes".

Here are some pictures illustrating my issue:

Workspace:

[image: Hulk in animation window]

Rendered png:
[image: Hulk in render]

#### [Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_k1-97vYIsifmFaYl9nMWhydWJUYjBDOHI3TUFaSEphUkdDRmk0aW51eHM2R2VBWGpvNkU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you have set the hair material to be a 'Mask' material. You can disable this by going to the 'Transparency' panel in the material options for the hair material and un-ticking the box next to 'Transparency':

[image]

If you want to use transparency for the hair you can set it to 'Z Transparency' or 'Raytrace'.

To get the hair to render as transparent you need to tell the material to use the transparency of the image you are using. On the hair material go to the texture panel and under the 'Influence' panel make sure 'Alpha' is turned on.

[image]

You can then turn the 'Alpha' value in the first screenshot to '0' as you are giving full control of the alpha over to the image.

Finally, because you are now using transparent textures, which will cast transparent shadows, you need to set *both* materials to 'Receive Transparent' in the 'Shadow' panel of the material options:

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help.
That seems to have solved my problem while in the workspace. But, when I try rendering, the hair appears as a grey helmet over Hulk's head: http://imgur.com/4oC3CLM

I think this has something to do with how the hair doesn't move properly with the armature. Hulk gets a big visor of hair when I turn off the transparency: http://imgur.com/o9dBqPe. (Even with transparency on, he has dreadlocks in front of his face).

Comment: That is because the hair isn't in a vertex group, so isn't being controlled by any bones, it's staying in place while everything else moves. But this is a separate issue to your question so I would suggest asking a new question if this comment doesn't help.

Comment: I've added the hair vertices to groups controlled by bones and it works likes a charm! But, back to the original problem, the rendered Hulk still has a grey helmet over his head: http://imgur.com/i4uvR8y. He looks a little better in the workspace with a full head of hair: http://imgur.com/4fTEGfH, but I really want him to render out as he looks with transparency turned on for the hair: http://imgur.com/8AbWVxj

Comment: I have updated my answer.